# Conectarme a una Api Rest con autenticación en C# para pasarle json

Tags: c#, api, rest, autenticación, net

Ojalá me puedan ayudar para enviar data a un APi Rest:

Esta es lo que dice documentación:
Headers
Headers must be set in order to authenticate and link the information to your account. MiEmpresa API    requires the following headers:

```
X-AUTH-TOKEN: Your API key in order to link all your API activity to your account, this can be  created through the web interface in Settings -> Advanced Settings.
```

Content-Type: As seen before, MiEmpresa's API is built to work in a JSON data format, so you must specify the request header to be 'Content-Type:application/json'.

El metodo es POST, y he generado mi LLave para conectarme:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que tengo es la que sigue:

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strURL);
        var jsondata = textBox1.Text;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(strName, strKey);
        request.Credentials = credentials;

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(strJsonData);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }
        try
        {
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream strReader = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (strReader == null) return;
                    using (StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(strReader))
                    {
                        string responseBody = objReader.ReadToEnd();
                        Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            // Handle error
        }
    }
```

y el error es:
"Error en el servidor remoto: (401) No autorizado."

Comment: que api es? estas seguro que tenes que pasarle las credenciales de esa forma?

Comment: Si tenes que definir un X-AUTH-TOKEN entonces usar las NetworkCredential no aplican. Tenes que definir un Header en el request

Answer (score 1):

Las llaves se deberian enviar como parte del `Headers`

```
request.Headers.Add("X-AUTH-TOKEN", "...");
```

Nota: entiendo que donde puse los "..." deberias usar la llave que generaste.

La asignacion del NetworkCredential deberias quitarla

Por otro lado aconsejaria evalues hacer uso de la clase `HttpClient` es mucho mas moderna para la invocacion de `Web APIs`

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-AUTH-TOKEN", "...");

     using (StringContent jsonContent = new StringContent(jsondata))
     {
         jsonContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

         using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(strURL, jsonContent))
         {
            var reponseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         }
     }
}
```